# using greedy algorithm search in lists

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Given a list of positive integer Items whose elements are guaranteed to be in sorted ascending order, and a positive integer Goal, and Output  is a list of three elements [A,B,C] taken from items that together add up to goal. The Output must occur inside the items list in that order (ascending order).

ex:

```
?- threeSum([3,8,9,10,12,14],27,Output).
Output=[8,9,10];
Output=[3,10,14].
```

someone helped me to reach this to this code
but it gives me singleton variables:[Input,Items] ,it didnt work
although iam not quite sure if this is a greedy algorithm search or not ?

```
 threeSum(Input,Goal,[A,B,C]):-
  permutation(Items, [A,B,C|Rest]),
  msort([A,B,C],[A,B,C]),
  msort(Rest,Rest),
  sum_list([A,B,C],Goal).
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72232401/output-is-a-list-of-three-elements-a-b-c-taken-from-items-that-together-add-up

Comment: it may help a lot ,but sadly it's not similar since i want it in informed search (greedy) :" 
thanks though <3

Comment: This can easily be an "informed" search because we know about the ascending order (can two consecutive elements be *equal*?), but what do you want from the "greedy" word in the title?

Comment: yep they can ,and i meant by it that i want to solve it with greedy algorithm search specifically of informed search types

Comment: Explain how you would recognize a "greedy" search here.

Comment: most probably as Tessellating heckler said down
i am not sure about the main idea to approach it by greedy search

Comment: I am a little puzzled by the use of `permutation` here. Permutations are the subsets of a set where order it important. For instance, the permutations of a set of 4 things taken two at a time — `{a,b,c,d}` — are `{a,b}`, `{a,c}`, `{a,d}`, `{b,a}`, `{b,c}`, `{b,d}`, `{c,a}`, `{c,b}`, `{c,d}`, `{d,a}`, `{d,b}`, `{d,c}`. What you would probably want are _combinations_: subsets where order is not important: `{a,b,c,d}` — `{a,b}` and `{b,a}` are the same combination. That gives you just `{a,b}`, `{a,c}`, `{a,d}`, `{b,c}`, `{b,d}`,  `{c,d}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nums_goal_answer(Input, Goal, [A,B,C]) :-
    length(Input, InputLen),    
    reverse(Input, RInput),     % 'greedy' interpreted as 'prefer larger values first'.
                                % and larger values are at the end.

    between( 1, InputLen, N1),   
    between(N1, InputLen, N2),  % three nested for-loops equivalent.
    between(N2, InputLen, N3),


    \+ N1 = N2,                 % can't pick the same thing more than once.
    \+ N2 = N3,

    nth1(N1, RInput, A, _),
    nth1(N2, RInput, B, _),
    nth1(N3, RInput, C, _),

    sum_list([A,B,C], Goal).
```

> someone helped me to reach this to this code but it gives me singleton variables:[Input,Items], it didnt work

The warning is because the code never looks at the numbers in the Input list. Without doing that, how could it ever work?

> although iam not quite sure if this is a greedy algorithm

is it taking the biggest things first? I don't think `permutation` will do that.

Comment: you are right about warning but i couldnt figure out how to fix that :"D
this did work for me , greedy algorithm is taking least/smallest things first
but can i list the output in ascending order instead ? 
although will i need a heuristic predicate to calculate the g(n) "least value at every move" ?

Comment: "*can i list the output in ascending order instead ?*" - You can change around the [A,B,C] to [B,C,A] in the header line. For the least value first, remove the reverse line and fix the RInput bits to work on Input. But I think greedy means 'biggest first', this is often a puzzle giving change in a shop. You want to give 50cents + 20cents + 5cents, rather than 1cent + 1cent + 1cent + 1cent + 1cent +...

Comment: thanks a lot mate for help , this is a link for greedy search in ai "not sure if links are allowed or not "
 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-algorithms-in-ai/#:~:text=In%20greedy%20search%2C%20we%20expand,a%20heuristic%20h(x).&text=h(x)%20%3D%20Estimate%20of,the%20node%20from%20the%20goal.

Comment: can i use moves here ? thinking about the list of input can i make them as nodes, approach them by greedy algorithm "lowest cost which reach the goal will be taken 
use open and closed lists open for searched nodes and closed for taken nodes that will help in making the goal 
also  Heuristic function to count the h(n) of searched nodes
is this applicable?

Answer (score 2):

A clpfd approach:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

threeSum(Input, Goal, [A,B,C]) :-
    Input = [First|Rest],
    foldl([N,M,T]>>(T = N\/M), Rest, First, Domain),

    [A,B,C] ins Domain,
    all_different([A,B,C]),
    chain([A,B,C], #>=),

    Goal #= A + B + C,

    labeling([max(A), max(B), max(C)], [A,B,C]).
```

Which has a bit of wrangling to turn the list of numbers into a domain, then says [A,B,C] must be in the list of numbers, must be different numbers, must be in descending order, must sum to the goal, and the clpfd solver should strive to maximise the values of A then B then C. (This probably won't work if the list can contain multiple of the same value like [5,5,5,3,2]).

e.g.

```
?- threeSum([3,8,9,10,12,14], 27, Output).
Output = [14, 10, 3] ;
Output = [10, 9, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using DCG:

```
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

three_sum_as_dcg(Total, Lst, LstThree) :-
    phrase(three_sum_dcg(3, Total), Lst, LstThree).

% When finished, remove the remainder, rather than add to LstThree
three_sum_dcg(0, 0) --> remainder(_).

three_sum_dcg(NumsLeft, Total), [N] -->
    % Use this element
    [N],
    {   three_sum_informed_search(NumsLeft, Total, N),
        succ(NumsLeft0, NumsLeft),
        Total0 is Total - N
    },
    three_sum_dcg(NumsLeft0, Total0).

three_sum_dcg(NumsLeft, Total) -->
    % Skip this element
    [N],
    { three_sum_informed_search(NumsLeft, Total, N) },
    three_sum_dcg(NumsLeft, Total).
    
three_sum_informed_search(NumsLeft, Total, N) :-
    NumsLeft > 0,
    % "Informed" search calc due to list nums not decreasing
    Total >= (N * NumsLeft).
```

Result in swi-prolog (note the efficiency):

```
?- numlist(1, 1000000, L), time(findall(L3, three_sum_as_dcg(12, L, L3), L3s)).
% 546 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (97% CPU, 4740036 Lips)
L3s = [[1,2,9],[1,3,8],[1,4,7],[1,5,6],[2,3,7],[2,4,6],[3,4,5]].
```

Comment: as a beginner in prolog i had no idea about any library , but thanks to you guys i am going to search for them and try to understand it and use it in next problems

Answer (score 1):

Restating the problem statement:

**Given that I have**

- A [source] list of positive integers, whose elements are guaranteed to be sorted in ascending order, and
- a positive integer indicating the target value.

**I want to find**

- an ordered subset of elements of the source list that sum to the target value

The simplest way is often the easiest (and the most general):

```
sum_of( _      , 0 , []     ) .  % nothing adds up to nothing.
sum_of( [X|Xs] , S , [X|Ys] ) :- % otherwise...
    S >  0 ,                     % - if the target sum S is positive,
    X =< S ,                     % - and the head of the list is less than or equal to the target sum
    S1 is S-X ,                  % - remove that amount from the target sum, and
    sum_of(Xs,S1,Ys) .           % - recurse down with the new target sum
sum_of( [_|Xs] , S , Ys     ) :- % then, on backtracking...
    S > 0 ,                      % - assuming that the target sum is positive,
    sum_of(Xs,S,Ys).             % - recurse down again, discarding the head of the list
```

This will find whatever combinations of however many list elements sum to the target value. It will find them from left to right, so

```
sum_of( [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 10, L ).
```

will, on backtracking successively find

```
L = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
L = [ 1, 2, 7    ]
L = [ 1, 3, 6    ]
L = [ 1, 4, 5    ]
L = [ 1, 9       ]
L = [ 2, 3, 5    ]
L = [ 2, 8       ]
L = [ 3, 7       ]
L = [ 4, 6       ]
```

If you want to change the order so it finds the largest values first, simply reverse the order of clauses 2 and 3 in `sum_of/3`:

```
sum_of( _      , 0 , []     ) .
sum_of( [_|Xs] , S , Ys     ) :-
    S > 0 ,
    sum_of(Xs,S,Ys) .
sum_of( [X|Xs] , S , [X|Ys] ) :-
    S >  0 ,
    X =< S ,
    S1 is S-X ,
    sum_of(Xs,S1,Ys) .
```

Now it will return the same set of solutions, just in the reverse order, starting with `[4,6]` and finishing with `[1,2,3,4]`.

Once you have solved the general problem, it's a simple matter of restricting it to a specified number of elements, for instance:

```
sum_of_n_elements(Xs,N,S,Ys) :- length(Ys,N), sum_of(Xs,S,Ys).
```

And to get just the 3-element subsets that sum to the target value:

```
sum_of_3_elements(Xs,S,Ys) :- sum_of_n_elements(Xs,3,S,Ys) .
```

https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/XKjdstla.pl

Comment: threeSum_([], 0, []).
threeSum_([H1|T1], 
Goal, [H1|T2]):-
 Goal2 is Goal-H1, 
threeSum_(T1, Goal2, T2).
threeSum_([_|T1], Goal, T2):-
 threeSum_(T1, Goal, T2).

itried this recursive approach earlier and it kinda worked but sadly i was asked to solve it in a greedy search approach not recursive
although thanks for the help i would love to see as much solutions as possible to help me understand prolog better