# Prolog Code that reachs a combination of numbers that sums up to a goal

Tags: prolog

I found this code and i just need to understand its idea and how is it working.
it outputs a list of numbers that sums up to a specific number (goal)

**example for a run:**

```
?- threeSum([3,8,9,10,12,14],27,Output).
   Output = [3, 10, 14] ;
   Output = [8, 9, 10] ;
   false.
```

**and here is the code:**

```
threeSum([H|T], Goal, Output):-
    solve(Goal,[H|T],Output).

subset([], []).
subset([H|T], [H|T1]):-
  subset(T,T1).
subset([_|T],T1):-
  subset(T, T1).

solve(MaxVal,Lin,Lout):-
    subset(Lin,Lout),
    sumlist(Lout,Val),
    Val = MaxVal.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using greedy algorithm search in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72277559/using-greedy-algorithm-search-in-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subset/2` has three different cases:

1. `subset([], []).`

   the base case: if the input list is empty, it returns also an empty list
2. `subset([H|T], [H|T1]):- subset(T,T1).`

   (this case is selected by default if the list is not empty): the first element of the output list is set to be equal to the first element of the input list. The tail of the list is then calculated recursively.
3. `subset([_|T],T1) :- subset(T, T1).`

   This case is selected, if the upper cases fail somehow: The head element of the input list is ignored and the tail is again calculated recursively.

The last part of `solve/3` just sums the values of `Lout`, compares it to the goal value, and if it fails, it backtracks, i.e. tries to find another solution for `subset/2`.

At first, the second case of `subset/2` is selected until the input list is empty.
So after the first `subset([3,8,9,10,12,14], Lout)` in `solve/3`, `Lout` becomes `[3,8,9,10,12,14]`.
The sum of this list is not equal to `MaxVal`, so it fails and the backtracking is initiated.
Now the last call of `subset/3` with a choice point, i.e. `subset([14], Lout)` fails, such that the third case of `subset/3` is called.
Therefore, after the first backtracking step, the value of `Lout` in `subset([3,8,9,10,12,14], Lout)` is now `[3,8,9,10,12]`.
This is again not equal to `MaxVal` and the next backtracking is started.
This goes on and on until `Val = MaxVal` is true.

Comment: Thank you for this great walkthrough, i got it now .